# Echo inside an echo

Tags: batch-file, buildforge

I'm trying to get to the value of a variable that's made up of two other variables. The only way I've gotten this to work is by using the FOR command with the /F switch and opening a second command shell:

```
SET A=This
SET B=That
SET ThisThat=YES!

FOR /F %I IN ('ECHO %A%%B%') DO cmd.exe /C ECHO %%I%
```

Output:

```
C:\>cmd.exe /c echo %ThisThat%
YES!
```

Does anyone know of a more elegant way to do this?

*UPDATE*

Here's a better explanation of what I was trying to accomplish (and was able to accomplish using y'all's - especially Aacini's - responses)

For a Rational BuildForge project, I have environment variables defined for each deployment target host. Example:

```
CURAM_HOST_NAME_DEV=DDW5T
CURAM_HOST_NAME_UAT=DUW5T
CURAM_HOST_NAME_TRN=DTW5T
CURAM_HOST_NAME_PRD=DPW5P
```

Another variable HOST contains the environment to deploy to. The deployment code is common for all deployment targets and uses the variable CURAM_HOST_NAME, so I needed to set this variable to the value of the variable that corresponds to the HOST being deployed to. The following does the trick:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_DEV=DDW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_UAT=DUW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_TRN=DTW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_PRD=DPW5P

SET HOST=DEV
CALL ECHO %%CURAM_HOST_NAME_%HOST%%%
SET HOST=UAT
CALL ECHO %%CURAM_HOST_NAME_%HOST%%%
SET HOST=TRN
CALL ECHO %%CURAM_HOST_NAME_%HOST%%%
SET HOST=PRD
CALL ECHO %%CURAM_HOST_NAME_%HOST%%%
```

Output:

```
DDW5T
DUW5T
DTW5T
DPW5P
```

In the BuildForge step, the code that sets this particular variable looks like the following:

```
.bset env "CURAM_HOST_NAME=`CALL ECHO %%%CURAM_HOST_NAME_%%HOST%%%%`"
```

(The BF parser requires additional %'s)

For a value of DEV for the HOST variable this produces the following in the log:

```
1026 5/3/14 7:34 PM STEP .bset env "CURAM_HOST_NAME=`CALL ECHO %%%CURAM_HOST_NAME_%%HOST%%%%`"
1027 5/3/14 7:34 PM EXEC .bset env 'CURAM_HOST_NAME' = 'DDW5BTH
```

Thanks a lot everyone. Wish I had the reputation that would allow me to upvote your answers!

Jozef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off

SET A=This
SET B=That
SET ThisThat=YES!

call echo %%%A%%B%%%
```

**EDIT**: *Updated answer to an updated question!*

```
@ECHO OFF

SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_DEV=DDW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_UAT=DUW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_TRN=DTW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_PRD=DPW5P

for %%a in (DEV UAT TRN PRD) do CALL ECHO %%CURAM_HOST_NAME_%%a%%
```

However, you should note that the !variable! replacement (together with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`) run *much faster* than the `CALL echo %%variable%%` trick:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_DEV=DDW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_UAT=DUW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_TRN=DTW5T
SET CURAM_HOST_NAME_PRD=DPW5P

for %%a in (DEV UAT TRN PRD) do ECHO !CURAM_HOST_NAME_%%a!
```

Perhaps you may want to review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: @sachadee
You guys are all awesome, but my question was very poorly put (actually, Thomas W pointed out the fallacy of it!) I went ahead and updated it.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "A=this"
set "B=that"
set "thisthat=YES^!"

echo !%A%%B%!
```

Note that the exclamation must be escaped in the assignment of thisthat because delayed expansion is enabled.